# How to make a border round out in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need you help me. I am newbie in flutter.

In flutter, I need to round out a widget, like the image below.
[image]

the red line indicate the border I want to make in flutter

Comment: You need to use custom paint in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can wrap the widget with Container and by applying decoration property you can make rounded corner or you can use ClipRRect.

{
```

//This is clipRRect you can wrap the child inside it

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
            ),
```

// if you use Container you can apply using this code as example
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
),
child: Text(''),
),

```
}
```